# How can I transform the rules to SWRL code?

Tags: java, jena, rules, pellet, swrl

Let's assume we have the following rule:

> Course(?x), teacherOf(?y,?x), worksFor(?y,?z) => coursePresentedInUniversity(?x,?z)

Is there any library in pellet or java to convert the above rule to SWRL code? for example, to the following:

```xml
<swrl:Imp rdf:about="#CoursePresentedInUniversityRule">
    <swrl:head rdf:parseType="Collection">  
        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
                <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#coursePresentedInUniversity" />
                <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#x" />
                <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#z" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
    </swrl:head>
    <swrl:body rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <swrl:ClassAtom>
            <swrl:classPredicate rdf:resource="#Course" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#x" />
        </swrl:ClassAtom>

        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#teacherOf" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#y" />
            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#x" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#worksFor" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#y" />
            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#z" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>

    </swrl:body>
</swrl:Imp>
```

I know that pellet can do the reverse (using `reasoner.getKB().getRules()`), but I don't know if there is anything to transform the representation to the SWRL XML code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting a string as SWRL rule in an ontology, according to [this document](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version3/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) some steps should be done: 1) the string should be parsed and tokenized. 2) SWRL rule should be created using SWRLRule and SWRLObjectProperties. 3) apply and save the changes in the ontology, 
For example, for `teacherOf(?y,?x)` we can write the following code:

```
    OWLObjectProperty teacherP= factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI
            .create(ontologyIRI + "#teacherOf"));

    SWRLVariable var1 = factory.getSWRLVariable(IRI.create(ontologyIRI
            + "#y"));
    SWRLVariable var2 = factory.getSWRLVariable(IRI.create(ontologyIRI
            + "#x"));
    SWRLObjectPropertyAtom teacherAtom = factory.getSWRLObjectPropertyAtom(
            teacherP, var1, var2);
    Set<SWRLAtom> SWRLatomList= new HashSet<SWRLAtom>();
    SWRLatomList.add(teacherAtom);
```

...

```
    SWRLRule teacherRule = factory.getSWRLRule(SWRLatomList,
            Collections.singleton(headAtom));
    ontologyManager.applyChange(new AddAxiom(testOntology, teacherRule ));
    ontologyManager.saveOntology(testOntology);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enter SWRL rules in presentation syntax in the [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/) editor then save your ontology in RDF/XML format. If you'd like to do the same in your code then you'll need to use the [ManchesterOWLSyntaxParserImpl](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5_0_1/org/semanticweb/owlapi/manchestersyntax/parser/ManchesterOWLSyntaxParserImpl.html) class from OWLAPI to parse the rule. You can then use OWLAPI to save the rule(s) in RDF/XML format.

Comment: Thanks @Evren, it would be great if you can give me an example (or point me out to the code) for parsing the rule Axioms using that library. – Enayat